# How do I DRY up my active nav links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to pass this into the controller so I don't have to repeat or ask for path names.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><%= link_to 'Breakfast', '/breakfast', class: ('active' if request.path == breakfast_path) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Lunch', '/lunch', class: ('active' if request.path == lunch_path) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Deli', '/deli', class: ('active' if request.path == deli_path) %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Contact', '/contact', class: ('active' if request.path == contact_path) %></li>
</ul>
```

Gems will not be considered an answer...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure passing it into the controller is a good solution -  it's concerned with view logic so I think the view is the right level to handle it on. Perhaps creating a helper method that wraps link_to would be the right approach. Here's an idea without having tested it:

```
  # YourHelper
  def nav_link_to(label, path)
     link_to(label, path, class: 'active' if path == request.path)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`active_link_to`](https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to) gem:

```
<% food = %w(breakfast lunch deli contact) %>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <% food.each do |meal| %>
        <li><%= active_link_to meal.titleize, eval("#{meal}_path") %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```